# `Cannot use 'in' operator to search for '_leaflet_id' in null` in testing

Tags: javascript, testing, leaflet, vitest, testing-library

I am implementing an integration test with Vitest 1.4.0 and testing-library/react 14.2.1 which renders the main app component. Simply by calling the testing-library `render()` function, I get this error:

```
TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for '_leaflet_id' in null
    at Util.stamp (proj/node_modules/leaflet/src/core/Util.js:55:21)
    at NewClass.hasLayer (proj/node_modules/leaflet/src/layer/Layer.js:203:10)
    at NewClass.getRenderer (proj/node_modules/leaflet/src/layer/vector/Renderer.getRenderer.js:20:13)
    at NewClass.beforeAdd (proj/node_modules/leaflet/src/layer/vector/Path.js:80:24)
    at NewClass.addLayer (proj/node_modules/leaflet/src/layer/Layer.js:169:10)
    at addLayer (proj/node_modules/@react-leaflet/core/lib/layer.js:9:19)
```

Leaflet runs fine when I run the application both in DEV and PROD mode and has a few points where it addsLayers to leaflet, making a reproduction hard to consider at the moment.